# Ubuntu server router - only 50% of upload bandwidth

Tags: ubuntu, performance, router, upload

I've changed my internet connection to 400 mbps download and 400 mbps upload.
Real speeds when computer connected directly to optical modem: 421/412 mbps for download/upload.

My network structure is:

```
Intranet <-> Router <-> Optical Modem
```

And i acquired a problem: router can't transmit at such speeds.

My ubuntu router had one 100 mbit ethernet card and one integrated gigabit card. And I've tryed to use Microtik RB950 as router, but it limits download/upload to 250/250.

I've bought second gigabit card and now my ubuntu router has two gigabit cards, but transmit speeds are 418/205 mbps. It is ok that download speed slowdown for a few megabits. But it is not ok, that there is only 50% bandwith for upload.

Intranet card is itegrated to motherboard. Works at 66mhz and 32 bit bus.

Internet cart is pci. Works at 33mhz and 64 bit bus.

I belive that i need to increase some buffers for tcp transmitting. But i do not know where to find this parameters. I've tried to increase sysctl parameters that i found:

```
net.core.rmem_max=12582912
net.core.wmem_max=12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem= 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem= 10240 87380 12582912
```

But it makes no effect. Can you advice parameters that will have effect? Or may be i'm missing something important?

Comment: Were you measuring download and upload separately, or at the same time?

Comment: Separately. In fact i have only two ways for measuring bandwith more than 100 mbps. Speedtest.net and analog of speedtest from my provider. Both of them gives same results.

Comment: Were you measuring speed at the router or at a machine connected to the router? If the former, you're not really measuring routing speed. If the latter, TCP settings won't have any effect because you're not using the router's TCP implementation -- it's just routing.

Comment: I'm measuring at machine connected to router. So there is no any settings for nat? Only on/off?